# Composerを利用しているアプリケーションのinstall/update時に自動的に特定の処理を実行したい

Tags: php, composer

Composerを利用しているPHPプロジェクトがあります。

このプロジェクトではリソースの前処理などいくつかの固有の処理があり、開発環境・CI環境・プロダクション環境を問わず、`composer install`や`composer update`が実行された時に必ず実行されるようにしたいです。

`composer.json`での設定や何らかのフックポイントでの拡張によって実現する方法があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install、update前であれば、`pre-install-cmd`, `pre-update-cmd`を
install、update後であれば、`post-install-cmd`, `post-update-cmd`を
利用することで可能なようです。

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

以下ドキュメントからそのまま抜粋しています。

composer.jsonを以下のようにして

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "MyVendor\\MyClass::postUpdate",
        "post-package-install": [
            "MyVendor\\MyClass::postPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "MyVendor\\MyClass::warmCache",
            "phpunit -c app/"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd" : [
            "php -r \"copy('config/local-example.php', 'config/local.php');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

各コマンドとして指定している名前空間などに併せて各クラスを用意しておけばいいようです。

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor;

use Composer\Script\Event;

    class MyClass
    {
        public static function postUpdate(Event $event)
        {
            $composer = $event->getComposer();
            // do stuff
        }

        public static function postPackageInstall(Event $event)
        {
            $installedPackage = $event->getOperation()->getPackage();
            // do stuff
        }

        public static function warmCache(Event $event)
        {
            // make cache toasty
        }
    }
```